# Can I update my user database with last login timestamp using mod_auth_mysql?

Tags: mysql, apache, .htaccess, apache-modules

Environment:

LAMP (CentOS 6.5, Apache 2.2.15-30.el6.centos, MySQL 5.5.36-1.el6.remi, PHP 5.4.26-1.el6.remi)

I have mod_auth_mysql installed and working properly. I am using .htaccess files to restrict access to users based off groups. The database structure is irrelevent, but I'll post anyway:

```
table: user_auth
user_name       varchar(25)
user_passwd     varchar(40)
last_modified   timestamp
last_login      timestamp
```

My auth_mysql.conf is very simple and generic. It looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
 AuthName "My Website"
 AuthType Basic
 AuthMYSQLEnable on
 AuthMySQLHost localhost
 AuthMySQLUser user
 AuthMySQLPassword pass
 AuthMySQLDB authDB
 AuthMySQLUserTable user_auth
 AuthMySQLNameField user_name
 AuthMySQLPasswordField user_passwd
 AuthMySQLGroupTable user_groups
 AuthMySQLGroupField user_group
</Directory>
```

So, my question is this: Is it possible to modify the auth_mysql.conf, .htaccess, MySQL trigger, etc to timestamp the last_login column in the user_auth table when a login is validated using mod_auth_mysql? I can't seem to find information about this anywhere, or maybe I;m just not using the right keywords. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and register a UDF function that will update the timestamp.
Then you can put this function into the modauthmysql's AuthMySQLUserCondition.

Might be easier to simply modify the modauthmysql.